# Plotting normal distributions

Tags: r, ggplot2, distribution, normal-distribution

I am trying to plot 3 examples of the normal distribution, however ggplot appears to be recognising the path as one continuous one rather than one stratified by the factor levels. I am relatively new to ggplot and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
set.seed(5872)

x<-seq(-7.5,7.5,0.1)
l<-length(x)*3
df<-data.frame(P=factor(rep(c("Mean: -1, SD: 0.5","Mean: 0, SD: 1","Mean: 1, SD: 1.5"),      each=l) ),
X=(c(x,x,x)), 
Y=(c(dnorm(x,-1,0.5),dnorm(x,0,1),dnorm(x,1,1.5))))

Normal<-ggplot(data=df,aes(X,Y,group=P,color=P))+
geom_path()+
scale_x_continuous("")+
scale_y_continuous("f(x)")+
scale_color_discrete("Parameters")+
ggtitle("Normal") + 
theme(plot.title = element_text(size=25,lineheight=.8, face="bold"))
```

How can I get ggplot to recognise the factors and plot with the 3 different colors? Rather than displaying one continuous path?

Comment: You have been bitten by R's silent vector recycling! You inadvertently made P 3 times too long. Then, X and Y were repeated once for each level of P. Just make one change `l <- length(x)` and everything works.

Comment: Ah okay thank you very much, I should have seen that!

Comment: +1 for a reproducible example in your first post. I would ask @bdemarest to post his observation as an answer so OP can accept it as correct.

Comment: @bdemarest, please post your comment as an answer so it can be accepted.

Comment: @bdemarest Ditto the above re: posting answer.

Answer (score 2):

A reproducible example, using hint from bdemarest:

```
   library(ggplot2)

   set.seed(5872)

   x<-seq(-7.5,7.5,0.1)
   l<-length(x)
   df<-data.frame(P=factor(rep(c("Mean: -1, SD: 0.5","Mean: 0, SD: 1","Mean: 1, SD: 1.5"),
            each=l) ),
   X=(c(x,x,x)), 
   Y=(c(dnorm(x,-1,0.5),dnorm(x,0,1),dnorm(x,1,1.5))))

   Normal<-ggplot(data=df,aes(X,Y,group=P,color=P))+
   geom_path()+
   scale_x_continuous("")+
   scale_y_continuous("f(x)")+
   scale_color_discrete("Parameters")+
   ggtitle("Normal") + 
   theme(plot.title = element_text(size=25,lineheight=.8, face="bold"))

   print(Normal)
```